# Search e-mail message data not including a specific phrase in Outlook

Tags: macos, email, ms-office, search

In Microsoft Outlook on MacOS - How do I search for e-mail messages that do not include a specific phrase in the message data, including the header?

Example: I could do a search for "stack" and it gives way to many "hits".
To reduce the number of messages, I could remove all hits that contain "stackexchange.com" both in the header and body, but as far as I can see, this is not possible.

In "Advanced Search" there is an option to search the body data, but not the header data of a message.

Comment: If the app stores the plain emlx data in some folder in ~/Library, `grep` can be used.